# fgets is influencing output

Tags: c, memory, structure, fgets

I'm having an hard time trying to figure out why my last fgets() seems to delete the value into "studente[0].nome", meanwhile when i use the scanf() that doesn't happen, so I would love if someone could explain me the problem and give me a new opportunity to learn. Thanks in advance.

```
struct studenti
{
    char nome[40];
    char cognome[40];
    short voto;
    char matricola[3];
};

#define N_STUDENTI 1

int main(void)
{
struct studenti studente[N_STUDENTI];
//float media = 0.0f;
char matricola[3];

printf("Inserisci i dati degli studenti nel Db:\n");

for(short i = 0;i<N_STUDENTI;i++)
{
    printf("Studente %d\n", i+1);
    fputs("NOME:", stdout);
    fgets(studente[i].nome, 40, stdin);
    fputs("COGNOME:", stdout);
    fgets(studente[i].cognome, 40, stdin);
    fputs("NUMERO MATRICOLA:", stdout);
    fgets(studente[i].matricola, 4, stdin);
    fputs("VOTO:", stdout);
    scanf("%hu", &studente[i].voto);
    getchar();
}

/* */
puts("INSERISCI MATRICOLA DELLO STUDENTE: ");
fgets(matricola, 4, stdin);//**HERE IS THE PROBLEM**
//whith a getcahr() works
printf("\n*NOME*: %s*", studente[0].nome);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is example input that shows the problem?

Comment: Aside: With `short voto;` use `"%hd"` and not `"%hu"`.  (or use `unsigned short voto;` and `"%hu"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do

```
fgets(studente[i].matricola, 4, stdin);
```

But the `matricola` definition is

```
char matricola[3];
```

That means you can go out of bounds of the array and have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

When using `fgets` with arrays (not pointers) then always use `sizeof` to get the size:

```
fgets(studente[i].matricola, sizeof studente[i].matricola, stdin);
```

That way you will always pass the correct size.

And of course you have the same problem after the loop when you read into the stand-alone array `matricola`.

If you really need a three-character string then you need to increase the size to `4` (to fit the null-terminator). If you need a *four* character string, then the size should be `5`.

Answer (score 0):

from [fgets()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)

```
  fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an EOF  or  a  new-
   line.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.  A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.
```

when you are declaring this array

```
struct studenti studente[N_STUDENTI];
```

you are allocating chunks of below memory segments where `matricola` is only about 3 bytes, which actually means you can put only 2 legal bytes in there..

```
{
    char nome[40];
    char cognome[40];
    short voto;
    char matricola[3];
};
```

however with below line there is every chance that you read past what your boundary is and actually corrupt neighboring chunks

```
fgets(matricola, 4, stdin);
```